# How to put the figure inside a circle using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I got a simple figure using turtle. But the problem is I dunno how to put that figure inside circle.
Code:

```
import turtle

painter = turtle.Turtle()
painter.pencolor("blue")
for i in range(50):
    painter.forward(100)
    painter.left(123*2)

painter.circle(70)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of trigonometry in my head and I figured the angle. Not sure if I got the radius correct though. Ideally figure out the coordinates of the center instead, but a quick and dirty solution is:

```
import turtle

painter = turtle.Turtle()
painter.pencolor("blue")
for i in range(50):
    painter.forward(100)
    painter.left(123*2)

painter.right(123)

painter.right(90)
painter.penup()
painter.forward(10)
painter.left(90)
painter.pendown()

painter.circle(70)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the turtle to the correct starting position. NOTE that's not the circle's center! It starts drawing the circle from its rightmost position - i.e., if you want a circle with radius 70 around (0,0), then move to (70,0), e.g.:

```
painter.penup()
painter.goto(70,0)
painter.pendown()
painter.circle(70)
```

FYI: I can't immediately figure out where the center of your drawing is, but I suspect it is NOT at (0,0). In all cases, you should place the turtle to the right of your shape's center, offset by the circle's radius, to make the circle go around it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to average the positions of your arbitrary image and then use that average as the center of the surrounding circle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

CIRCLE_RADIUS = 70
POLYGON_LENGTH = 100
POINTS = 50

screen = Screen()
painter = Turtle()
painter.speed('fastest')

painter.pencolor("blue")

total = Vec2D(0, 0)

for _ in range(POINTS):
    painter.forward(POLYGON_LENGTH)
    total += painter.position()
    painter.left(246)

x, y = total * (1.0 / POINTS)  # Vec2D can multiply by scalar but not divide

painter.penup()
painter.goto(x, y - CIRCLE_RADIUS)
painter.setheading(0)
painter.pendown()

painter.circle(CIRCLE_RADIUS)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]